# How to specify local domain with Invoke-WmiMethod

Tags: powershell

I am trying to connect to a remote computer using a local administrator account via WMI using the powershell cmdlet `Invoke-WmiMethod`.

I can get it to work using a domain account. However, when I try to use a local account, it assumes that I want to use an AD account. The local account does exist on the remote computer.

I'm generating the PSCredential object with the following command:

```
$cred = Get-Credential account01
```

I'm passing the credential object to Invoke-WmiMethod with this command:

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -Path Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList "cmd.exe /c echo hello world" -ComputerName adcomputer -Credential $cred
```

When I look at the event viewer logs on the remote computer, it shows that it is attempting to use ADDOMAIN\account01 instead of attempting to log in using the local account database.

Attempting to enter ".\account01" to signify the domain is the local computer does not work, I get the following error after trying to create the credential object:

[image]

Is there any way to use this cmdlet to connect to a remote computer using a local administrator account (on remote host)?

Comment: Use the hostname of the remote computer as the realm: `adcomputer\account01`

Comment: `COMPUTERNAME\USERNAME` does not work?

Comment: I'm actually doing this in a loop over many PCs, I could do that but I feel it would be a lot cleaner if theres another way that specifies local computer domain without hard coding the domain name. Using the computer's hostname, I would have to re create a different credential object every iteration.

Comment: I think the validation error comes from the credential UI, manually constructing a credential object with `.\...` should still work. Give `$cred = [pscredential]::new('.\account01', $(Read-Host "Input password" -AsSecureString))` a try

Comment: Well, surely you already have the list of PC's. I don't think recreating the credential object each iteration is an issue unless you're prompting for it every time. I assume the password is the same for each machine, as it's the username you seem to be concerned about. You could read the password as a SecureString at the beginning of the script and then use `$Creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("$ComputerName\username", $Password)` on each iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the help, looks like more than one way to do this. @MathiasR.Jessen this is exactly what I was looking for and is now working. Post an answer if you want it accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific error/validation hint you receive is part of the credential GUI component used by Windows PowerShell's `Get-Credential` implementation.

That means you can work around it by manually constructing your credential object:

```
$cred = [pscredential]::new('.\account01', $(Read-Host 'Input password' -AsSecureString))
```